# C++ two function program - passing values back and forth between two functions [debug]

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I think I am nearing a more elegant solution to a problem. I am trying to create a program that inputs text files of numbers, reads all the first digits, counts the total number of occurences for values 1-9, and then displays the analysis information. the first time I tried to do this, I ran the analyzeData function once with 9 different conditionals. I have since moved to tried to have analyzedata(string filename) pass a basic loop [for (int i; 1 <= 9; i++)] through countLines(string filename, int number) and then display the new counts.

however, i have come to a point where i think it's finished but it will not run. **I have three errors on lines 59, 81, and 88.** I went back through to check for brackets and semi colons. I have put a considerable bit of time and energy trying to make something efficient rather than a colossal copy and paste mess of doom.

sidenote-  I am working in Xcode and the only "output" i can see because it will not run is "sh: PAUSE: command not found".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

// function to pass digit value to. analyzeData will
// call this function for each digit value 1-9

int countLines(std::string filename, int number) 
{
    int count=0;
    std::ifstream file;
    std::string first_digit;

    file.open( filename.c_str() );
    if ( !file.good() )
    {
        std::cout << "**ERROR: file not found!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        file >> first_digit;

        if (number == 0)// calling analyzeData with number=0 will compute total # lines / input values
        {
            while (!file.eof())
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        else if (number != 0)
        {
            if (first_digit[0] == number)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

    file.close();
    return count;
}

void analyzeData (std::string filename)
{
        std::ifstream file;
        std::string first_digit;

        file.open( filename.c_str() );
        if ( !file.good() )
        {
            std::cout << "**ERROR: file not found!" << std::endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << filename << std::endl;
            std::cout << countLines(filename,0) << std::endl; //total lines
            for (int i=1;i <= 9;i++) //sends i through countLines for each digit value
            {
                std::cout << i << ": " << countLines(filename, i) << std::endl;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            file.close()
        }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    analyzeData("***put file path here***");
    analyzeData("***put file path here***");
    analyzeData("***put file path here***");
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    return 0;
}
```

Any help or constructive criticism is welcome.

As I was writing this I had a moment of realization! On line 45 I set a conditional for a string index character to be equivalent to a int variable.... this must be a source of error somehow. Can anyone show me how to make the int variable be read as a string? .c_str()??

Comment: To insert the code, just paste it in, highlight it and hit CTRL+K. Now please mark the lines where the errors occur.

Comment: Any chance you could tell us what the errors on lines 59, 81 and 88 are? I'm looking at your code and it's not obvious. Knowing what the error messages are might give me a clue.

Comment: Your moment of realization is very good, but your solution is wrong. The answer is to convert the char to an int by substracting `'0'`, `if (first_digit[0] - '0' == number)`

Comment: `PAUSE` is a DOS (Windows) command - you should either delete the `system(PAUSE);` line or replace it with something more portable.

Comment: In `countLines`, the `else` is missing a closing brace.
In `analyzeData`, `file.close()` is missing a semicolon.
After fixing those, it compiles at least.

Comment: `while (!file.eof()) { count++; }` This will loop forever, as you don't actually read from the file inside the loop. Try this instead: `std::string line; while (std::getline(file, line)) { count++; }`

Comment: The question is quite well formulated; there are a few things which could be improved, at least for future questions you should consider a few things: (1) When encountering (compile) errors, it's always *very* useful to actually state the error messages when looking for help (2) the question as it is at the moment is rather vague - it gives one big blob of code and asks for comments. In this format, it would be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I kept finding minor annoyances, so I just rewrote it, following your same basic structure. For what it's worth, [have a look.](https://ideone.com/vGSwsy) I've put in a decent number of comments.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the responses! 
@jrok, i will try cntrl+k for formatting my code.

Comment: line 59 - std::ifstream file; Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

Comment: line 80 - } //end of analyzeData function Expected ';' at end of declaration

Comment: line 88 - analyzeData("/Users/Galen/Documents/CS 109/HW5/citypopulations.txt"); Expected '}'

Comment: These errors seem like cosmetic damage from a deeper laying problem.

@BoBTFish I definitely missed a bit of the nuance you did with the code. Especially any differences made for different platforms or IDEs. however, i did specifically note that you stopped analyzeData from opening the file because countLines already does this! this made sense to me intuivitely, but i wasn't sure how to pass the std::string filename to EITHER function without opening the file inside of it. where does string filename exist? only in the parameters?

Comment: @nyarlathotep i will use the codereivew! thank you!

Comment: @UICBioEngr The `std::string` containing `"f1"` exists only during the execution of the first line of `main`. It is created as as temporary object from the string literal `"f1"`, and then passed to the functions by *reference to `const`*. That is, roughly, they point back to that one object. I did this because they don't need to change it or keep it around, so there is no need to copy it. They can then use it in any way they please, as long as they don't change it.

Comment: @BoBTFish bob, i think i understand the idea of passing the parameter value to the function. i think it was throwing me off that i can define a function with one or more parameters, but not even use those parameters or anything like them in the definition. thank you for catching my syntax errors with semi-colons and my infinite and non-advancing loops. i have added a line to my line reading loops to advance the file each loop till it reaches the end. i have a question about getline(file, line) though!

Comment: @BoBTFish is getline a built in c++ function? why is it not defined anywhere outside of its use in while loops?

what are getlines parameters and why are they not defined inside the parameter ()'s? e.g. countlines (STRING filename, INT xy)

Comment: @UICBioEngr `analyzeData` takes `filename` as an argument, then uses it to call `countLines`. `countLines` takes `filename` as an argument, then uses it to open `file`. [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is a function in the Standard Library (see the `std` namespace). It is included in the `<string>` header. It takes an input stream (`file` in our case), and a `string` to read to (`line` in our case). There is a another version that takes a delimiter character too, in case you want to break on something other than a newline character, but that's unusual.